# How to express "The work is as difficult to do as easy it sounds" in a less awkward way?

Tags: phrase-request

How do I rephrase the sentence

> "The work seems easy to do, but is equally difficult".

Is there a way of saying it using "As much as"?

Or can I say,

> "The work is as difficult to do as easy it sounds" ?

The latter sentence looks grossly incorrect to me.

Comment: _The work is easier said than done._ _The work seems easy to do but is actually difficult._ A more common expression is: _The job is harder than it sounds._

Comment: Because ***easy*** and ***difficult*** are diametrically *opposite*, it's semantically problematic to say something is *equally* as easy as it is difficult (regardless of the fine distinction between *actually being* and *appearing to be* easy or difficult). So use one of @Joe's idiomatically established alternatives.

Comment: The job isn't as easy as it might seem.

Comment: It's [*easier to say than to do*](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22easier+to+say+than+to+do%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers firstly, thank you for the answer :)
Secondly, I was wondering if  "The work is as difficult to do as easy it sounds" can be a possible sentence? I can understand what you've explained about using two opposite words in a sentence such as this one but is it syntactically wrong altogether?

Comment: @TamyP: No, your version wouldn't be considered "grammatical" by anyone. Feasibly one might be able to make a case for *It's as difficult to do as it sounds easy* being "syntactically valid", but it's so awful no-one would actually *use* it. If you really want to make this specific comparison you could perhaps use *It's as difficult to do as it is easy to say*, but I doubt anyone could express the relationship succinctly and elegantly by contrasting ***do*** and ***sounds*** like this (incompatible because "it" in *do the work = **object***, but in *the work sounds easy = **subject***).

Comment: "As easy as it sounds, it's actually hard."

Comment: @FumbleFingers It may be awful, but it expresses OP's stated intention :o)

Answer (score 1):

We usually use

> Easier said than done.
>   X is harder than it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You could rephrase it this way :

> As much as the work might sound/seem easy to do it is (acctually) difficult.

Or

> As much as you would think the work is easy, it is (acctually) difficult

Answer (score -1):

The work is as easy as it seems like.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Oscar. Your answer would be more useful if your included any research you have done, references to sources,etc. [**Here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is a link to our page on writing a good answer. We hope you will answer more questions, and ask some of your own.